# polygon matrix calculation for viscosity matrix

Tags: php

I am writing a program which needs different value of gas viscosity at different temperature for respective gases. Data which i have is given below. I am new in programming in  php . can anyone please give me the logic behind it. so that i can get viscosity at any required tempertaure through the program. thanks

```
Data for viscosity calculation (dyn. visc. [Ns/m² = kg/ms]; Source: VDI Wärmeatlas                      
Temp. [°C]  0     100        200             300         400         500

CO2 1,37E-05    1,82E-05    2,22E-05    2,59E-05    2,93E-05    3,24E-05

O2  1,92E-05    2,43E-05    2,88E-05    3,29E-05    3,67E-05    4,03E-05

H2O 9,00E-06    1,25E-05    1,61E-05    1,97E-05    2,33E-05    2,69E-05

N2  1,66E-05    2,09E-05    2,47E-05    2,82E-05    3,14E-05    3,42E-05
```

Comment: My advice would be to fit a curve using least squares fit for viscosity = c0 + c1*T + c2*T^3 + ...., one for each gas, and then have a map or associative array where the gas is the key.

Comment: I am still not sure how to solve it. Could you please elaborate it.or give me an example of codes. Also i am not able to find anything on internet related to it. please guide me for my further research.

Comment: No, I cannot/will not solve it for you.  Start with one curve for CO2: Can you plot your six points with temperature as the independent variable and viscosity as the dependent?  If yes, does it look like a straight line or does it have some curvature?  Can you Google for least squares fit?  It can be done with Excel.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i have implemented least square fit and i am getting results. although curve is not a straight line ,hence it answer has  a little variation

Comment: I just posted the four curves for you, including fit equations. Should be easy now.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily fit your data in Excel.  Here's a plot that shows the result, along with the 2nd order polynomial:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the right answer. In case if anyone need it, I am posting it out here:

```
class baseViscosityCalc {

    public $arViscosity = array(
        array(0, 1.37e-05, 1.92e-05, 9.00e-06, 1.66e-05),
        array(100, 1.82e-05, 2.43e-05, 1.25e-05, 2.09e-05),
        array(200, 2.22e-05, 2.88e-05, 1.61e-05, 2.47e-05),
        array(300, 2.59e-05, 3.29e-05, 1.97e-05, 2.82e-05),
        array(400, 2.93e-05, 3.67e-05, 2.33e-05, 3.14e-05),
        array(500, 3.24e-05, 4.03e-05, 2.69e-05, 3.42e-05)
    );

    public function getViscosityData($DCat) {

        $arValue = array(
            'Temperature' => 0.0,
            'CO2' => 0.0,
            'O2' => 0.0,
            'H2O' => 0.0,
            'N2' => 0.0
        );

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->arViscosity); $i++) {
            $arValue['Temperature'] = $DCat;
            if ($DCat < $this->arViscosity[0][0]) {
                $arValue['CO2'] = $this->arViscosity[0][1];
                $arValue['O2'] = $this->arViscosity[0][2];

                $arValue['H2O'] = $this->arViscosity[0][3];
                $arValue['N2'] = $this->arViscosity[0][4];
                break;
            }
            if ($DCat > $this->arViscosity[count($this->arViscosity) - 1][0]) {
                $arValue['CO2'] = $this->arViscosity[count($this->arViscosity) - 1][1];
                $arValue['O2'] = $this->arViscosity[count($this->arViscosity) - 1][2];

                $arValue['H2O'] = $this->arViscosity[count($this->arViscosity) - 1][3];
                $arValue['N2'] = $this->arViscosity[count($this->arViscosity) - 1][4];
                breaK;
            }

            if ($DCat > $this->arViscosity[$i][0] && $DCat < $this->arViscosity[$i + 1][0]) {

                $factor = ($DCat - $this->arViscosity[$i][0]) / ($this->arViscosity[$i + 1][0] - $this->arViscosity[$i][0]);
                $arValue['CO2'] = $factor * ($this->arViscosity[$i + 1][1] - $this->arViscosity[$i][1]) + $this->arViscosity[$i][1];
                $arValue['O2'] = $factor * ($this->arViscosity[$i + 1][2] - $this->arViscosity[$i][2]) + $this->arViscosity[$i][2];
                $arValue['H2O'] = $factor * ($this->arViscosity[$i + 1][3] - $this->arViscosity[$i][3]) + $this->arViscosity[$i][3];
                $arValue['N2'] = $factor * ($this->arViscosity[$i + 1][4] - $this->arViscosity[$i][4]) + $this->arViscosity[$i][4];
                break;
            }
        }
        return $arValue;
    }
}
```